# Unable to replace path using sed

Tags: sed

How can i replace a path with another path in file using sed command, And when it is used as a variable in script it is working.

`sed -i "s/"system_filter = /etc/define_filter_file"/"system_filter = /usr/local/etc/file_regex"/g" /etc/exi.conf.bak`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape all slahes in the provided paths and change opening and terminating quotes to single quotes.

```
sed -i 's/"system_filter = \/etc\/define_filter_file"/"system_filter = \/usr\/local\/etc\/file_regex"/g' /etc/exi.conf.bak
```

The command is expressed as:

```
sed -i 's/path1/path2/g'
```

Path1 and path2 can not clearly contains `/` as this will be confused with the whole expression.

Comment: Or just use a different delimiter for the `s` command, something less frequent in paths: `sed -i 's!path1!path2!g'`.

Comment: @manatwork is there anything wrong with this answer such that it does not deserve an upvote ?

Comment: @istheEnglishway, definitely not. Just the question is so incomplete that personally I can not tell for sure whether the answer is really for that question. (I'm suspecting the question owner actually would need it without the double quotes, but hard to tell as no test case was provided.)

Comment: @manatwork: There can be more than one solution to any given problem :)

Comment: @manatwork ok so, if there is no reason to not upvote it why didn't/haven't you done so ? I'm not calling you out or anything, I'm just genuinely interested in why someone who clearly knows an answer is correct doesn't upvote it.I even have history of trying to find out  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6418/on-the-paucity-of-voting

Answer (score 4):

From the infotex manual of GNU sed (see `info sed`):

> The syntax of the `s` (as in substitute) command is
>   `s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS`.  The `/` characters may be uniformly
>   **replaced by any other single character**<sup>1</sup> within any given `s` command.
>   The `/` character (or whatever other character is used in its stead)
>   can appear in the REGEXP or REPLACEMENT only if it is preceded by a `\`
>   character.

i.e. use <kbd>|</kbd> as the delimiter between the REGEXP and the replacement and the sed command becomes:

```
sed -i 's|"system_filter = /etc/define_filter_file"|"system_filter = /usr/local/etc/file_regex"|g' /etc/exi.conf.bak
```

or in short:

```
sed s|/some/path|/alternate/path/|
```

which is much easier than the alternative, escaping a large number of forward slashes:

```
sed s/\/some\/path/\/alternate\/path\//
```

---

1.<sub>(The `sed` man page on OSX explicitly excludes the backslash <kbd>\</kbd> and newline characters from the above qualification of *"any other single character"* )</sub>

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259083/replace-unix-path-inside-a-file/259087#259087